# Did the Torah Sages discuss evolution

Tags: sources-mekorot, animals, science, chazal, biology

Are there examples in chazal of the sages discussing the phenomena of micro-evolution (or macro), i.e. adaptive changes in creatures.

Answer (score 8):

There's a story in the Talmud - [Shabbat 31a](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.31a?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) - about a guy who tried (unsuccessfully, as it turned out) to win a bet by provoking [Hillel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_the_Elder) to anger. He posed three questions about phenotypic variations in certain human populations:

1. מפני מה ראשיהן של בבליים סגלגלות
   א"ל
   בני שאלה גדולה שאלת מפני שאין להם חיות פקחות

   [He asked,] "What is the reason that the Babylonians heads are wide?"
   He said to him,
   "My son, you are asking a great question. It is because they do not have intelligent midwives."
2. מפני מה עיניהן של תרמודיין תרוטות
   אמר לו
   בני שאלה גדולה שאלת מפני שדרין בין החולות

   [He asked,] "What is the reason that the Ethiopians' eyes are bleary?"
   He said to him,
   "My son, a big question you have asked. It is because the live surrounded by sand."
3. מפני מה רגליהם של אפרקיים רחבות
   א"ל
   בני שאלה גדולה שאלת מפני שדרין בין בצעי המים

   [He asked,] "What is the reason that the Africans have wide feet?"
   He said to him,
   "My son, a big question you have asked. It is because the live between the bays."

<sup>(Talmud text and translations are from [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.31a?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all).)</sup>

The first response seems to be pretty clearly a matter of physical conditions during (the very first moments of) individuals' lifetimes, and therefore not a matter of hereditary evolution.

[Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) (s.v. ["שדרים בין החולות"](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Shabbat.31a.31.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)) offers two explanations for each of the other two answers, and in each case, one explanation appears to be in terms of environmental effects on individuals, while another - the one preferred by Rashi - appears to be more like the adaptation of the population to the environment, possibly in a hereditary manner:

- 2-Environmental: Ethiopians' eyes are bleary because the wind blows the surrounding sand into them.
- 2-Adaptation: Read "תרוטות" to mean "round," rather than "bleary." "Because they live surrounded by sand, *the place<sup>1</sup> changed them*, such that the crack of their eyes is not as long as ours, letting the sand in."

  <sup>1: Or possibly, "the Omnipresent"</sup>
- 3-Environmental: Because they live between they bays, Africans go barefoot, so their feet end up wider than those of people who constrict their feet with shoes.
- 3-Adaptation: "Similarly [to the adaptation explanation of the eyes answer], the Africans' feet are wide so that  they don't sink into the bays."

<sup>(Paraphrases and, where indicated by quotation marks, translations are mine.)</sup>

It sounds to me that Rashi's preferred explanations of Hillel's second and third answers clearly express physical adaptation of the respective populations to their environments. Neither Hillel or Rashi say anything about possible mechanisms for this adaptation, such as Darwinian [natural selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution#Natural_selection), Lamarckian [inheritance of acquired characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamarckism), simple acquisition of the same adaptive characteristics by all individuals during their lifetimes, or instantaneous mutation via open miracle. In addition, if I recall correctly, not everyone agrees that Hillel's answers were serious analyses of the natural phenomena rather than allegorical lessons or non-serious dismissals. So, this is not a slam-dunk, but according to Rashi's preferred explanations, I think we can fairly say that Hillel *may* have been describing instances of micro-evolution.

Comment: If you know commentaries that would substantiate my "not everyone agrees that Hillel's answers were serious analyses ...," I'd appreciate your [edit]ing them in.

Comment: Agreed that at one level, they're playing "ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer" ... but I like the possibility that he's trying to get Hillel mad with racial slurs, and Hillel responds with a biology lesson.

Comment: have heard that Hillel was just toying back to this guy at his own game. http://youtube.com/watch?v=RDBhfdqRE3w great audio

Comment: DID you read RASHI? "ואף כאן אני אומר כן ומפני שדרים בין החולות **שינה אותם המקום** שלא יהא סדק של עיניהם ארוך כשלנו "  - Rashi clearly states what I wrote in my answer - the merciful G-d created them in such a way that they will not suffer from big opened eyes.

Comment: @AlBerko, what does אותם mean in that context? Individuals or the population? What is the timescale over which the place changed them? An instant, a lifetime, generations, or longer? Even assuming Rashi presents the lone definitive explanation of the gemara, I see this explanation as at least as likely supporting my interpretation as conflicting with it.

Comment: Oh, המקום in Rashi refers to G-d, not the place. Read it again.

Comment: @AlBerko, how do you know that that's the case in this instance? Also, don't we believe that every mechanism in nature comes from God? (Indeed, doesn't the nickname המקום hint in that direction?) Why should we assume that this passage is talking about a נס נגלה rather than a נס נסטר, assuming that it's ascribing the changes to a willful act of God?

Comment: ... What is the difference, with respect to whether adaptation to the environment was contemplated by Chazal or not (the question at hand), between "God adapted them to their environment" and "They were adapted to their environment"? (Given the underlying axiom that God runs the world.)

Comment: Scientifically **this is an absurd** - 1500 years (from after the flood to Babylon) will not lead to any evolutionary change! Can you explain black people by evolutionary developing the black skin in some 500-1000 years?

Comment: @AlBerko The question is whether Chazal discussed adaptive changes in [populations of] creatures, not whether it happened or not, or over what timescale, or whether the adaptation Chazal discussed fits with any particular scientific explanation.  I've presented an example of Hillel discussing what, according to one line of commentary, were adaptive changes in a population. It's not clear what mechanism he was thinking of (if any - observation of the effect is valuable without understanding the mechanism), but that's irrelevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 5):

This one is imaginative, but someone told this to me years ago and it does seem somewhat compelling.

The gemara in [Berachos 61b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.61b.7?with=all&lang=bi) records a famous parable said by Rabi Akiva where he compares a Jew without Torah to a fish being taken out of the water. The story has a fox who was trying to trick the fish. The fox argued:

> He said to them: Do you wish to come up onto dry land, and we will reside together just as my ancestors resided with your ancestors?

These words seem to say that the ancestors of the fox lived with the ancestors of the fish.

Perhaps he is even implying his ancestors lived in the water with the fish, and that it is possible for the fish to now come live on the land. There is much that can be read into this. Of course it would be interesting to note that the fox was trying to trick the fish, and is refuted by the fish, but at the same time we have no reason to say this actual line is assumed false, just inapplicable at that point in time. In fact, if it was a blatant lie, it would have been detrimental to his argument. There is definitely room to delve into this.

Answer (score 2):

Shulchan Aruch introduces the laws of cross-breeding/cross-grafting species by saying that "two plants or animals may appear to be different, but are actually the same species but grew differently because of conditions or locations."

Comment: do you think it means he held of darwinian common ancestry? it surely does not fit the plain meaning of genesis "of its kind..."

Answer (score 1):

Bamidbar Rabba 9:34 has a story with Rabi Akiva who explained to a black king that his child was white not because his queen had been unfaithful, but because she had been focusing on white images while they were together. 
Rabi Akiva explained that this was the phenomenon behind Yaakov's treatment of Lavan's sheep in Bereishis 30.

According to this Chazzal, we now have a pasuk in the Torah discussing this!

There is another similar Chazzal that discusses exterior visual influences and the effect on the outcome of the child's appearance. But the idea is not of Jewish origin.

See Gittin 58a where the Romans would have beautiful pictures so as to influence the appearance of the child. After the Churban they would tie the beautiful children of Bnei Yisroel to their bed for this purpose. The appropriate passuk from Devarim 28 quoted there concerning this treatment reads גם כל חלי וכל מכה אשר לא כתוב בספר התורה הזאת.

Comment: Hmm. It never occurred to me to associate the notion of [maternal impression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_impression) with microevolution.

Comment: Living in one of the most ethnically diverse neighborhoods in the world, I've noticed how quickly any given minority has children that look more and more 'American' than their parents. So to me this is a davar pashut.

Comment: Related to your most recent comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/432

Comment: Interesting. Ty.

Comment: @user6591, I [have seen](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/433/2) such a difference take place in an immigrant himself. A lot can change without congenital difference.

Answer (score 0):

found this

the Zohar (3:10a) quotes an even earlier book by Rav Hamuna Saba of the 2nd temple era

> "The Entire earth and those around it, spin round in a circle like a
>   ball, both that at the bottom of the ball and those at the top. All
>   G-d's [human] creatures, wherever they live on the different parts of
>   the ball, look different because the air is different in each place,
>   but they stand erect as all other human beings. Therefore, there are
>   places in the world where, when some have light, others have darkness;
>   when some have day, others have night. There is a place in the world
>   where day is long and night is but a short time (arctic regions)...
>   And this secret has been passed on by the men of wisdom - the wisdom
>   of Torah"

seems clear given all men descended from Adam

http://www.yeshshem.com/torah-and-science-4.htm

Comment: Keep reading till you get to the part where Rashbi tells him he's wrong and the earth is not round rather it has multiple layers like an onion and he goes on a sea voyage, falls down into the middle of the earth, meets the humans who are not descended from Adam and goes back and cries for ever doubting the words of his Rebbi.

Comment: Also note that nothing in the Zohar should be assumed to have been intended to be taken literally.

Comment: @user6591, it says no such thing. The "layers like an onion" is talking about the rekiim, and is in the name of R' Yehuda. (Rashbi isn't mentioned there at all.) Doesn't say that R' Nehorai fell into the middle of the earth, but that "he went down in known paths in the heart of the sea and came out from under the sea to a certain settlement." Also doesn't say that the people there weren't descended from Adam, just that "they were all small, and were praying, but he didn't know what they were saying." About the only thing right in your comment is the last sentence, and even that is misapplied.

Comment: וּמִנְּהוֹן בְּא'. וְחֵיזוּ דְּאִלֵּין לָאו כְּאִלֵּין.
וַחֲבֵרֵינוּ יוֹשְׁבֵי הַדָּרוֹם רָאוּ בְּסִפְרֵי הַקַּדְמוֹנִים וּבְסִפְרוֹ שֶׁל אָדָם, שֶׁכָּךְ מְחֻלָּקִים כָּל הָאֲרָצוֹת הַלָּלוּ, שֶׁכֻּלָּם נִמְצָאִים לְמַטָּה כְּמוֹ אוֹתָם הָרְקִיעִים שֶׁלְּמַעְלָה, אֵלּוּ עַל אֵלּוּ וְאֵלּוּ עַל אֵלּוּ, וּבֵין כָּל אֶרֶץ וְאֶרֶץ רָקִיעַ מַפְרִיד בֵּין זֶה לָזֶה, וְלָכֵן כָּל הָאֲרָצוֹת מְפֹרָשׁוֹת בְּשֵׁמוֹת, וּבֵינֵיהֶן גַּן עֵדֶן וְגֵיהִנֹּם, וְיֵשׁ בֵּינֵיהֶן בְּרִיּוֹת מְשֻׁנּוֹת אֵלּוּ מֵאֵלּוּ, כְּמוֹ שֶׁלְּמַעְלָה, מֵהֶן בִּשְׁתֵּי פָנִים וּמֵהֶן בְּאַרְבַּע

Comment: עִלָּאִין עַל כֹּלָּא, כְּגַוְונָא דִּלְעֵילָּא.
וְאִם תֹּאמַר, הֲרֵי כָּל בְּנֵי הָעוֹלָם יָצְאוּ מֵאָדָם, {{אינו כך, שלא}} וְכִי יָרַד אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן לְכָל הָאֲרָצוֹת וְהוֹלִיד בָּנִים? וְכַמָּה נָשִׁים הָיוּ לוֹ? אֶלָּא אָדָם לֹא נִמְצָא אֶלָּא בָּעוֹלָם הָעֶלְיוֹן הַזֶּה מִכֻּלָּם, שֶׁנִּקְרָא תֵבֵל, כְּמוֹ שֶׁאָמַרְנוּ, שֶׁכָּתוּב {{משלי ח}} {{משחקת בתבל ארצו}} וַיְצַו לְתֵבֵל אַרְצוֹ. וְהַתֵּבֵל הַזּוֹ אֲחוּזָה בָּרָקִיעַ שֶׁלְּמַעְלָה וְנֶאֱחֶזֶת בַּשֵּׁם הָעֶלְיוֹן. זֶהוּ שֶׁכָּתוּב {{תהלים ט}} וְהוּא יִשְׁפֹּט תֵּבֵל בְּצֶדֶק. בְּצֶדֶק וַדַּאי. מִשּׁוּם כָּךְ בָּנָיו שֶׁל אָדָם נִמְ

Comment: וְלָא מְהֵימְנֵי.
רַבִּי נְהוֹרַאי סָבָא פָּרַשׁ לַיָּם הַגָּדוֹל, וְהִתְרַעֵשׁ הַיָּם, וְנֶאֶבְדוּ כָּל אוֹתָם שֶׁהָיוּ בַסְּפִינָה, וְהִתְרַחֵשׁ לוֹ נֵס, וְיָרַד בִּשְׁבִילִים יְדוּעִים לְלֵב הַיָּם, וְיָצָא תַחַת הַיָּם לְיִשּׁוּב אֶחָד, וְרָאָה מֵאוֹתָן הַבְּרִיּוֹת כֻּלָּן קְטַנּוֹת, וְהָיוּ מִתְפַּלְלִים תְּפִלָּה, וְלֹא יָדַע מָה אוֹמְרִים. הִתְרַחֵשׁ לוֹ נֵס וְעָלָה. אָמַר, אַשְׁרֵיהֶם הַצַּדִּיקִים שֶׁמִּשְׁתַּדְּלִים בַּתּוֹרָה וְיוֹדְעִים נִסְתְּרֵי הַסּוֹדוֹת הָעֶלְיוֹנִים. אוֹי לְאוֹתָם שֶׁחוֹלְקִים עַל דִּבְרֵיהֶם וְלֹא מַאֲמִינִים.
קישור ישיר לדף זה

Comment: @Shamiach aramaic is a hard language. Here is the hebrew translation ^^^^^^^

Comment: @Shamiach I will concede that it was Rabi Yehuda though. Its been some years since I've seen it.

Comment: @Shamiach The first paragraph says "all the lands below are similar to the rokias above. And between each land there is a rokia separating them" 2nd paragraph: "if you will say that all men come from Adam, (this is not so), did Adam go down to all the lands and have children? How many wives did he have? Adam was only found on the top land which is called Tevel". 3rd: "there was a storm at sea and everyone on the boat was lost, but a miracle happened and he went down through the known paths to the heart of the sea, and came out under the sea to a certain community and saw etc".

Comment: @user6591 and then it goes on to say that Rav Hamnuna "explained it further" - so his statement isn't contradicting the previous one but clarifying it. And R' Nehorai's upset at not believing what the chachamim say doesn't mean that he's sorry for following R' Hamnuna rather than R' Yehuda, but that he ever doubted R' Hamnuna's statement in the first place. All told, your understanding of the Zohar leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, the sages' opinion says the exact opposite of evolution, i.g they firmly believed, that G-d created different landscapes and made the people of those countries fit their surroundings.

Read Rashi on Shabbos 31a carefully :

> "ואף כאן אני אומר כן ומפני שדרים בין החולות שינה אותם המקום שלא יהא סדק של עיניהם ארוך כשלנו ""

מקום by Rashi refers to G-d, not place. That proves exactly that: **G-d being merciful and knowledgeable and caring, had foreseen those people's needs and created them differently (or altered them if you wish) to fit those conditions**.

This is consistent with a general outlook that G-d created all animals and plants and weather conditions and landscapes to fit each other. The fact of evolution would suggest, that G-d created creatures unfit for their environment.

The very attempt to interpret the sages "in favor of evolution" lies in our mental bias of projecting our knowledge on other people.

Comment: That Gemara has [already been discussed here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60357/9682) as a proof that Chazal discussed evolution. If you don’t want to follow Rashi that’s fine, but at least put in the effort to find a different Rishon to rally behind if you’re going to do that.

Comment: @DonielF Exactly the opposite, but don't rush to judge me. The idea of Evolution did not exist in that times, and the only explanation for physical differences between species and human nations was G-d's wisdom, that created them in a perfect match to their surroundings. My interpretation of the discussion you cited is exactly opposite of yours, as you project your current knowledge to your interpretation. It proves, that the sages simply rejected that gentile by nothing as he could not grasp the idea of G-d's wisdom.

Comment: @DonielF BTW, this is very common to American Haredis that are far more flexible and ready for compromise that we, Israelis. Try to say this idea of the Sages supporting the evolution in Hebron or Ponivetz, or Gur, and see the reaction.

Comment: So at least try to explain Rashi to fit your own projection of your own interpretation, and then you’re free to attack me about doing the same. (Before you explain further in the comments, I mean that you should edit it into the answer.)

Comment: @DonielF Sorry, are you serious? Rashi reads explicitly "**ואף כאן אני אומר כן ומפני שדרים בין החולות שינה אותם המקום שלא יהא סדק של עיניהם ארוך כשלנו "** - the merciful G-d created them in such a way they will not suffer from sand like us to fit their surroundings.

Comment: Is this answer suggesting that Creation (as in Bereishit) included diverse populations of humans? Alternatively, is it suggesting that there were subsequent acts of new creation of populations of humans? If not, then "שינה" means, per its plain meaning, "altered," not "created differently," as there was only one act of Creation of humans, consisting of a population of two. Given that, I do not understand the relevance of the theological point "G-d created all animals and plants and weather conditions and landscapes to fit each other." ...

Comment: ... After Creation, humans migrated from Eden to other environments and [were] changed, yielding diverse populations. Assuming the changes were helpful for living in those environments (as half of the explanations in Rashi explicitly do), these are quite literally adaptations of the forms of these humans to the environment.

Comment: 1. You forgot the flood - all mankind came from 3 sons of Noah  - 2000 BCE. 2. שינה means G-d created them differently. There's no idea of heredity in Torah. To wit, when Itzhak was born he was "purposefully created" to resemble Abraham. As I said earlie, scientifically this is an absurd - 1500 years (from after the flood to Babylon) will not lead to any evolutionary change! Can you explain black people by evolutionary developing the black skin in some 500-1000 years?

Comment: That seems a peculiar translation of שינה. Can you show other instances in which Rashi uses this word to mean "create differently," and not "alter something that exists"? In any case, this concept of new creation of human populations other than Noach's descendants in/for different locations is very new to me. Can you point to other Torah sources that invoke it? Finally, I'm not sure why you keep bringing up scientific explanation of proposed mechanisms; this question is about whether Chazal talked about a phenomenon, not about whether contemporary science would confirm a particular mechanism.

Comment: My claim is, that **at no point in time, the Jewish sages knew any scientific facts more than the surrounding nations**. However this fact seriously damages our self-esteem, so we try hard to use the vague language of Torah and Talmudic interpretations to prove otherwise. This is especially true for American Jews that are pressured hard to justify their religiosity.

Comment: Also, as Rambam clearly points in Rosh Chodes, **during the first Babylon Exile we lost all of the "scientific" oral tradition we had from Moses **, and all our sages had during the second Temple times is the wisdom of the Greeks (and some others).  This explains R' Yehuda's "נראים דבריהם מדברינו", that the Greek's perception of the Solar system seems more plausible than the sages'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72427/discussion-between-isaac-moses-and-al-berko).