# Zohar / Facial features

Tags: sources-mekorot, geography, zohar

Shalom all.
I once read/heard that the Zohar says that when Jews move to a certain location, then those Jewish people's facial features change to look like the people that they live among.
Does any one have a reference to the topic that I am talking about?
Thank you

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/432/759

Comment: The Maharitz Chiyus on Shabbos 31a with the story of Hillel and the questioner who asked why different countries have different physical features, says that Hillel's response was that each country affects the features of the children born there in different ways and that he meant to answer this exact question of how if everyone comes from Adam Harishon there are so many different variations.

Comment: just look at ashkenazi jews versus sefardi jews.

Answer (score 1):

Is it this? Anyhow searching the terms here might help you find it.

https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.90b.8?vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi

אָמַר רַבִּי חִיָּיא תָּא חֲזֵי, כַּמָּה אִנּוּן רַבְרְבִין עוֹבָדוֹי דְּקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא, דְּהָא אוּמְנוּתָא וְצִיּוּרָא דְּבַּר נָשׁ אִיהוּ כְּגַוְונָא דְעָלְמָא, וּבְכָל יוֹמָא וְיוֹמָא קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא בָּרֵי עָלְמָא מְזַוִּוג זִוּוּגִין כָּל חַד וְחַד כְּדְקָא חָזֵי לֵיהּ, וְהוּא צִיֵּיר דִּיוּקְנֵיהוֹן עַד לָא יֵיתוּן לְעָלְמָא.

---

R' Chiyya said: Come and see how mighty are the Holy Blessed One's works! For behold the artistry and form of a man is like (the world/the people around him). And every day the Holy Blessed One creates the world (anew) and pairs matches and unions, each one (resulting from which?) in the way that you see it - but yet He made the form of their faces/semblances even before they came in the world!

Answer (score 0):

The rambam in the introduction to avot called shmeonah prokim le HaRambam talks about this.

Comment: Shemonah Prakim is fairly big. Do you have a more exact reference/link to the relevant section/can quote where he refers to this?